# WiX Toolset - check for all installation prerequisites at once (conditional installation)

Tags: wix, windows-installer

WiX Toolset allows to create conditional installation to check if all prerequisites are installed on the system. The problem is that this conditions are checked separately. I would like to show all of not yet installed prerequsities to user in one list. Is there any way to achieve that in WiX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The WiX Condition element when used under a Fragment or Product element represents an entry in the [LaunchCondition Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369752%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and is processed by the [LaunchConditions Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The behavior you see is a limitation of that underlying feature.

Here's a blog article I wrote about this 7 years ago:

[Short Comings of LaunchConditions](http://blog.iswix.com/2006/07/short-comings-of-launchconditions.html)

Sadly, Microsoft has never taken my recommendations for improvement.  So instead of using the Condition element you'll have to write your own custom table and custom action to do the processing.

I have sample code for this in InstallScript and C# but I've never written it in C/C++.

Here is a stripped down example in InstallScript.  Read it as pseudocode for refactoring in C/C++.  You'll need to also create the custom table used by the SQL query, define and schedule the custom action ( I typically schedule it after FindRelatedProducts ) and also create a custom dialog for displaying the error text.  All of this is WiX XML that is not included.

```
hDatabase = MsiGetActiveDatabase(hMSI);
MsiDatabaseOpenView(hDatabase, "SELECT `Condition`, `Description` FROM `CustomLaunchConditions` ORDER BY `Ordering`", hView );
MsiViewExecute(hView, 0);

if( MsiViewFetch(hView, hRecord) == ERROR_SUCCESS ) then
  loop = TRUE;
  while(loop)
    nvBufferSize = MAX_STRING;
    MsiRecordGetString(hRecord, 1, svProperty, nvBufferSize );

    if(!MsiEvaluateCondition(hMSI, svProperty)) then
      nvBufferSize = MAX_STRING;
      MsiRecordGetString(hRecord, 2, svValue, nvBufferSize );
      hFormatRecord = MsiCreateRecord(1);
      MsiRecordSetString(hFormatRecord, 0, svValue);
      nvBufferSize = MAX_STRING;
      MsiFormatRecord(hMSI, hFormatRecord, svResult, nvBufferSize);
      svWarningMessage = svWarningMessage + svResult + "\r\n";
    endif;

    if( MsiViewFetch(hView, hRecord) != ERROR_SUCCESS) then
      loop = FALSE;
    endif;
  endwhile;
  MsiSetProperty(hMSI, "CustomLaunchConditionsText", svWarningMessage);
endif;
```

Comment: Christpher thanks for your answer. Is there any chance that you could share this code you mentioned? It would be very helpful for me.